# Two different definitions for a directed set

Tags: relations, upper-lower-bounds

A set $S$ is called upward directed set if it's reflexive and transitive, and for every two elements $a,b \in S$ there exist a $c \in S$ such that $c$ is an upper bound for both $a$ and $b$,e.g. $a\leq c$ and $b \leq c$.

The definition of a downward directed set is analogous, and a set which is both upward directed set and downward directed set is called **directed set** or filtered set.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_set) states that:

> Directed sets are a generalization of nonempty totally ordered sets. That is, all totally ordered sets are directed sets.

By definition every totally ordered set is reflexive and transitive and every two elements are related with respect to the relation defined on the set, but how it can be shown that every two pairs of elements are bounded above/below?

Also can someone give me an example of a filtered set that is not a totally ordered set?

The statement is not true for partially ordered sets, since for example if we consider a set $P=\left\{1,2,3\right\}$ and define a partially ordered set $S$ such that:

$(S,⊆):=\left\{\left\{1\right\},\left\{2\right\},\left\{3\right\},\left\{1,2\right\},\left\{2,3\right\}\right\}$

There deos not exist any upper bound for $\left\{1,2\right\}$ and $\left\{2,3\right\}$, although they both are bounded below by $\left\{2\right\}$.

There exists another definition for filtered set (upward directed set) that states:

> A directed set is a set $S$ with a preorder such that every finite subset of $S$ has an upper bound.

The abonnement between these two definitions is that they both are preorder, but the first one states that every **two elements are bounded above**, and the second one states that every **finite subset of $S$ is bounded above**.

Clearly if let the two elements to be in a set then the set will be a finite set since it's cardinality is a finite value, and also the set containing the two elements will be bounded above, since each elements contained in that set is bounded above, but I think the second definition give us a more generalized concept since the subset may have more than two elements and still bounded.

**Finally can someone prove the theorems in the two yellow boxes and verify my examples?**

Comment: For any set $S$ let $\Bbb (S)$ be the set of all subsets of S, i.e. $\Bbb P(S)=\{T: T\subseteq S\}$ (a.k.a. the power-set of $S$). For $a,b\in\Bbb P(S)$ let $a\le b$ iff $a\subseteq b.$ Now with $c=a\cup b$ and $d=a\cap b$ we have $d\le a\le c$ and $d\le b\le c...$  But if $S$ has at least 2 members, take $x,y\in S$ with $x\ne y.$ Then with $a=\{x\}$ and $b=\{y\}$ we have $\neg (a\le b)$ and $\neg (b\le a),$ so $\le$ is not a total order... Another name for total order is linear order.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet,so this is an example of a filtered set which is not a totally ordered set? if so then can we say that in $\mathbb P(S)$ every two elements are bounded above and below?because for example if $S=\left\{1,2\right\}$ and $\mathbb P\left(S\right)=\left\{\left\{\right\},\left\{1\right\},\left\{2\right\},\left\{1,2\right\}\right\}$, then the upper bound for $\left\{2\right\}$ and $\left\{\right\}$ is $\left\{2\right\}$ and the lower bound for both of them is $\left\{\right\}$, but $\left\{2\right\}$ and $\left\{1\right\}$ are not related to each other via inclusion, am I right?

Comment: Right. Partial orders that are filtered but not total orders are everywhere. Another example: For $m,n\in \Bbb N$ let $m\le^*n$ iff $n/m\in \Bbb N.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, And if $S=\left\{1,2,3\right\}$ and $\mathbb S=\left\{\left\{1\right\},\left\{2\right\},\left\{3\right\},\left\{1,2\right\},\left\{1,3\right\},\left\{2,3\right\}\right\}$, then $\mathbb S$ is a partially ordered set which is not a totally ordered set, also it's not a filtered set, right?

Comment: yes that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Theorem.** Let $S$ be a set endowed with a preorder "$\le$". Then each finite subset $F$ of $S$ has an upper bound if and only if 
each two-element subset $F$ of $S$ has an upper bound.

*Proof* (with details).  ($\Rightarrow$) This is trivial, because each two-element subset $F$ of $S$ is finite, so it has an upper bound.

($\Leftarrow$) We prove the following claim “each finite subset $F$ of $S$ has an upper bound” by an induction with respect to a number $|F|$ of elements of the set $F$. If $|F|=1$ then $F=\{x\}$ for some $x\in S$ so $x$ is an upper bound for each (that is, for a unique) element of $S$. If $|F|=2$ then the claim holds because each two-element subset $F$ of $S$ has an upper bound. Assume that the claim if proved for some natural number $n$ and let $F$ be a subset of $S$ such that $|F|=n+1$. Let $\{x_1,\dots, x_{n+1}\}$ be the elements of $F$. Put $F’=\{x_1,\dots, x_n\}$. Since $|F’|=n$, by the inductive hypothesis the elements of the set $F’$ have a common upper bound, say $x\in S$. The set $G=\{x,x_{n+1}\}$ consists of two elements, if $x\ne x_{n+1}$ and of one element,   if $x=x_{n+1}$. So $|G|=1$ or $|G|=2$. By the cases considered in the beginning of the induction,  all elements of $G$ have a common upper bound, say $y$. We claim that $y$ is a common upper bound for elements of $F$. Indeed, let $z$ be any element of $F$. Only the following two cases are possible.

1. We have $z=x_{n+1}$. Then $y$ is an upper bound for $z$ since $y$ is an upper bound for $x_{n+1}$.
2. We have $z\ne x_{n+1}$. Then, since $z\in F$, we have $z\in F’$. Then $z\le x$, since $x$ is a common upper bound for elements of $F’$. Since $x\le y$, by the transitivity of the relation “$\le$”,  we have $z\le y$, so $y$ is an upper bound for $z$.

Thus, anyway, $y$ is an upper bound for $z$, which follows that $y$ is a common upper bound for elements of $F$. This finishes the step of the induction, and, therefore, the proof of the theorem. $\square$

Comment: @ Alex Ravsky,I really surprised that you posted for my question,it's my honor.I was thinking why did you put the upper bound of $F'$  (which is denoted by $x$) and $x_{n+1}$ in a set and why did not you say "either $\color{red}{x\le x_{n+1}\;\; \text{or}\;\; x_{n+1}<x}$" and then continue this way, but after this I find out that generally this is not true ,since $x$ and $x_{n+1}$ are elements in a preorder set $S$ and it may happen that neither $x\le x_{n+1}$ nor $x_{n+1}<x$,am I right?

Comment: Also can I set $n=0$ as the base case for induction and say an empty set $\color{red}{trvially}$ has upper/lower bound(s) (I'm saying "trivially" because the trueness of this case does not use the assumption that each two-element subset $F$ of $S$ is finite) and for the case $n=1$ our set is $F=\{x\}$, as you said the set would be a singleton and this set is bounded since $a\le a$ and this is because the reflexivity property of $\le$ (again this case does not use the assumption that each two-element subset $F$ of $S$ is finite), but for $n\ge2$ we should use our assumption, exactly as you did.

Comment: @user715522 Your first comment is right. Also I add that according to the chosen proof, we don’t need to consider an alternative “$x<x_{n+1}$ or $ x_{n+1}<x$”. Yes, formally we could start the induction from $n=0$, but usually I’m trying not to start induction from so degenerated cases, because their consideration is based on different intuition than the general case and this difference can lead to errors in arguments either for  the general case or for the degenerated case.

Comment: I got it, but in this special case if we start induction with $n=0$ then would my second comment be true?

Comment: @user715522 Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\le$ be a total order.
Assume $x,y$ in the ordered set.
Case $x \le y$:  $y$ is upper bound of $x$ and $y$
Case $y \le x$:  Similar.

Comment: do you have any example of a filtered set that is not a totally ordered set?

Comment: Sets cannot be reflexive.